# How secure are classes used by JSP Pages?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If I have a form on a JSP page, and the form passes its data to a simple java file (.class) that I have written, which returns some sort of data that is printed to the user on a new page. Would that java file itself be accessible to users of the website ? In other words, would it be possible for a user to locate that .class file and download it ? If so, how can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 3):

no they would not be able to download the class files, the servlet container running your application would have all the class files under WEB-INF/classes. Anything under the WEB-INF folder is not publicly visible.

Comment: So no extra level of security would be needed, to keep the classes under WEB-INF from being downloaded ?

Comment: Correct. The web container does not allow you to access that as a resource.

Comment: I just noticed that in Eclipse, the classes are being added to "\build\classes" instead of "\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes", is this the way Tomcat 7.0 handles classes now ? Or should I explicitly move them to the directory you mentioned ? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jonathan - build\classes is just for eclipse, when you create a war file the classes would be inside WEB-INF/classes folder always.

Answer (score 0):

short answer is no.

Longer answer, any .class file that runs on the client side they will have access to but any class that runs on the server side they will not have access to.

Comment: Thanks! I came to that conclusion on my own, but I wasn't sure, it was mainly why I decided to go with JSP/Servlet instead of turning my classes into an applet.

Comment: @Jonathan - you aren't really getting Servlet API - Not transferring classes to applet is not a reason to use servlets over applets. They both are completely different technologies and not alternative to each other.